# XQuery grouping multiple relational items

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, grouping, relation

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Manufacture>
<Fabrics>
    <Fabric fid="123456-1234" name="bmw"/>
    <Fabric fid="123456-2344" name="audi"/>
    <Fabric fid="123456-3454" name="fiat"/>
</Fabrics>
<Sections>
    <Section sectionID="1" fabricID="123456-1234" />
    <Section sectionID="2" fabricID="123456-2344" />
    <Section sectionID="3" fabricID="123456-1234" />
    <Section sectionID="4" fabricID="123456-3454" />
</Sections>
<Cars>
    <Car carID="1" section="1"/>
    <Car carID="2" section="3"/>
    <Car carID="3" section="2"/>
    <Car carID="4" section="4"/>
    <Car carID="5" section="3"/>
    <Car carID="6" section="2"/>
    <Car carID="7" section="3"/>
    <Car carID="8" section="1"/>
</Cars>
</Manufacture>
```

How do I achieve the following:

> Show total number of cars for each fabric!?

that is:

```
<result fid="123456-1234" name="bmw" total="5"></result>
<result fid="123456-2344" name="audi" total="2"></result>
<result fid="123456-3454" name="fiat" total="1"></result>
```

fid in Fabric tag is related to fabricID in Section tag, its sectionID is related to section in Car tag
appreciate any help :)

Comment: Could you show what you have tried so far? Also: The desired result more resembles the output of XSLT processing than a simple XPath query. Are you sure you want pure XPath?

Comment: One more thing: Do you require the result to be written with explicit closing tags? Or could it also be regular XML tags `<result ... />`?

Comment: I have tried many queries but no success:
<result>{
let $fabric :=for $fabrics in doc("data.xml")//fabrics
 return $fabrics

let $section :=for $sections in doc("data.xml")//sections
 return $sections

let $car := for $cars in doc("data.xml")//cars
 return $cars
let $v:= for $ss in $fabric/fabric/@fid
 for $dd in $section/section[@sectionID=$ss]
 for $bb in $car/car[@section=$dd/@sectionID]
 order by $ss
 return $dd

let $tot:= for $i in (1 to 23)
  where $v[$i]/@fid = $fabric/fabric[2]/@fid
  return ($v[$i]/@fid)


return <fabric>{($tot)}total: {count($tot)}</fabric>
}</result>

Comment: No, the answer can be a regular XML tag i.e. <result ... />

Comment: What is this syntax you are using bracing your XPath expressions?

Comment: I'm very newbie in xquery, I dont know how else i could write!?

Comment: I have to apologize: I wasn't familiar with XQuery yet. I do have an XPath expression that solves your problem but it still needs to be wrapped into XQuery which I took as a synonym for XPath so far (shame on me!). So your syntax is probably fine! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

**data.xml**

```
<Manufacture>
    <Fabrics>
        <Fabric fid="123456-1234" name="bmw"/>
        <Fabric fid="123456-2344" name="audi"/>
        <Fabric fid="123456-3454" name="fiat"/>
    </Fabrics>
    <Sections>
        <Section sectionID="1" fabricID="123456-1234" />
        <Section sectionID="2" fabricID="123456-2344" />
        <Section sectionID="3" fabricID="123456-1234" />
        <Section sectionID="4" fabricID="123456-3454" />
    </Sections>
    <Cars>
        <Car carID="1" section="1"/>
        <Car carID="2" section="3"/>
        <Car carID="3" section="2"/>
        <Car carID="4" section="4"/>
        <Car carID="5" section="3"/>
        <Car carID="6" section="2"/>
        <Car carID="7" section="3"/>
        <Car carID="8" section="1"/>
    </Cars>
</Manufacture>
```

**XQuery**

```
let $doc := doc('data.xml')/Manufacture
for $fabric in $doc/Fabrics/Fabric
return
    <result total="{count($doc/Cars/Car[@section=$doc/Sections/Section[@fabricID=$fabric/@fid]/@sectionID])}">
    {$fabric/@*}
    </result>
```

**Results**

```
<result total="5" fid="123456-1234" name="bmw"/>
<result total="2" fid="123456-2344" name="audi"/>
<result total="1" fid="123456-3454" name="fiat"/>
```

Comment: +1 Did not learn XQuery quickly enough... Beaten by three minutes :-)